# Are TCP source and destination port numbers sufficient to determine which packets carrying TLS records belong to a specific TLS session?

Tags: tcp, tls1.3

I am studying how to determine which packets carrying TLS records belong to the same TLS session (much like Wireshark does).

For a given TLS record that belongs to a specific packet(s), are we always able to determine its relation to its origin ClientHello record simply by comparing its TCP-level source-destination numbers to source-destination numbers of every TCP packet that carried a ClientHello message in the past? Or do we need additional information to make that conclusion?

When multiple ClientHello records are sent in succession, I noticed that client origin port at the TCP level was always a different number (incremented by 1), hence this question.

I know TCP sessions can be reused for subsequent TLS connections, but am I right to assume that only a single TLS session exists at one point in time under a single TCP session?